# How to add FavIcon ExtJS

Tags: extjs, favicon

I am getting an failed to load resource error on my project because it cannot find the favicon.

I was wondering if anyone can let me know how to add the FavIcon for ExtJS.

Thanks!

Comment: try this `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">` in your `index.html`. you can change icon from your local resource.

Comment: It could not find that img, however I was able to get it by putting the favicon.ico img directly in the root folder. Thanks for your help.

Comment: mostly welcome man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it by putting the favicon.ico img directly in the root folder.